# Ordenar TreeMap

Tags: java

Buenas estoy intentando ordenar un TreeMap donde tiene como key un tipo File y un int que es el peso en kb del File algo asi

TreeMap<File,Integer>

no encuentro nignuna formula de ordenar la lista por medio de su clave de menor a mayor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal como lo planteas no se puede hacer porque la comparación es solo para las claves (el File). Sin embargo con una estructura intermedia si puedes

```
Map<File, Integer> sizes = new ....
sizes.put(f1, 20);
sizes.put(f2, 30);
....

TreeMap<File, Integer> tree 
    = new TreeMap<>( (key1, key2) -> sizes.get(key1) - sizes.get(key2));
for(File f : sizes.keySet()) {
    tree.put(f, sizes.get(f));
}
```

Es una solución parcial porque insertar en `tree` un File que no está en `sizes` te dará un `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html

Según la documentación oficial, podrías hacerlo si le pasas un comparador al constructor del treemap. Creo que podrías pobrar con Comparators.reverOrder().

No puedo probarlo ahora. Perdón si no es la respuesta correcta.

Comment: El problema esque no se muy bien como funciona eso del comparador debido a que este tipos de listas se me dan muy mal.
no hay algun tipo de .sort? para ordenar la clave del Tremmap es Integer

Comment: @GolpeCelestial te recomiendo entonces que, antes aprender sobre la clase `TreeMap`, trates de familiarizarte con los comparadores. De otro modo nunca podrás sacarle provecho a los `TreeMap`s.